# How i can bring second "navbar" div inline with first "navbar" div?

Tags: html, css

I am try to put the div nav2 on the same line as nav 1 but it just not going up what is the problem i even try float but it not working also

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
}

#navbar {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 display: 
 }

#navbar ul {
 list-style: none;
}

#navbar ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 5px 0px 20px;
 }

 #nav2  {
  float: right;
 }
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="navbar">
        <div id="nav1">
            <ul>
                <li>How it works</li>
                <li>Why Company?</li>
                <li>Pricing</li>
                <li>About us</li>
                <li>Resource center</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="nav2">
            <ul>
                <li>Get stated</li>
                <li>Log in</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="head">
        <div>
            <h3>Company</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Invert Like a idiot</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>because money is lame</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect that Both "nav1" and "nav2" on the name line just like normal navbar but i want "nav2" on the right side that why i make it div "nav2"

Comment: Maybe provide us with a rough sketch. How the final result should look like

Comment: Try [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) | add `display: flex` to your `#navbar`

Comment: [link](https://www.google.co.uk/search?biw=1366&bih=625&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=E2HKXIS5DYqQlwS-saT4Cg&q=homepage+design&oq=home+page&gs_l=img.1.2.0i67j0j0i10j0j0i10l2j0l4.4985.5458..7501...0.0..0.192.753.0j4......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i7i30.wt2_UaJfa6c#imgrc=2rPcWduHFhfKeM:) here Gupta

Comment: its almost work just "nav2" not moving to right side now :3 @vaku

Comment: Try adding `flex: 1` to both the `#nav1` and `#nav2`

Comment: i find the answer using display:flex; on "navbar" div and then margin-left:auto; on "nav2" div :D thanks vaku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want to do :

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    height: 50px;
}

#nav1 ul, #nav2 ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-auto-columns: minmax(min-contant, max-content);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    
    list-style: none;
}

#nav1 ul {
    padding-left: 20px;
    justify-content: left;
}

#nav2 ul {
    padding-right: 20px;
    justify-content: right;
}



#head {
    padding: 50px 20px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="navbar">
            <div id="nav1">
                <ul>
                    <li>How it works</li>
                    <li>Why Company?</li>
                    <li>Pricing</li>
                    <li>About us</li>
                    <li>Resource center</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="nav2">
                <ul>
                    <li>Get stated</li>
                    <li>Log in</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer is incorrect but anyway i find the answer by using display:flex; on "navbar" div and then margin-left:auto; on "nav2" div

Comment: * {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
}

#navbar {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 }

#navbar ul {
 list-style: none;
}

#navbar ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 5px 0px 20px;
 }

 #nav2  {
  margin-left: auto;
 }

this is the answer

Comment: @FahadMir same result .. different method

Comment: oops my bad i miss one selector D: that why its a mess